# Syntax-basics for using ST_ApproximateMedialAxis() function in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, geometry, syntax

I tried to solve a problem I had in QGIS (see [Simplifying multiple lines to create central axis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/319412)).

I just need to know how the correct syntax works to use the function [`ST_ApproximateMedialAxis(geometry geom)`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ApproximateMedialAxis.html)

I successfully added the geometry to the pgAdmin4 Geometry Viewer with the query

```sql
select geom
from public.bufferrail
```

so that seems to be correct.

But how to include this geometry as argument to the function?

```sql
SELECT ST_ApproximateMedialAxis (select geom from public.bufferrail);
```

does not work. I tried several variations, with no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct query is:

```sql
SELECT
    uid,
    ST_ApproximateMedialAxis(geom)
FROM
    public.bufferrail;
```