# Generalizing railways from OpenStreetMap using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, openstreetmap, generalization, railroad

I have dataset of railways from OpenStreetMap. It is really detailed. But i want to make generalization for map scale 1:500 000: remove small details of the railways and short branches. I`ve used Collapse Dual Lines To Centerline, Collapse Road Detail, Merge Divided Roads, Thin Road Network tools For generalization of roads.

What is the best way for generalization of railway lines?

UPDATE

i removed the railways that were marked in OSM as abandoned, or tram, or sidding, or crossover lines etc. But there are too many lines without additional tags to filter.

example, Odessa railways before and after my manipulations.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: A simple Google search throws up [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=generalizing+rail+networks).

Comment: Which technique that you tried gave you your best result?  What was that technique in detail?  If its results did not meet your requirements then in what way did it fail?

Comment: @Hornbydd, thank you! most search results look like theory (research papers, generalization presentations, etc.), without detailing how to achieve the results they are talking about. As an example, here's the Merge Divided tool and its results. I'm a beginner at Arcgis and I want to have more practitioner tips.

Comment: @PolyGeo, i updated post, pls have a look.

Comment: Try [Integrate](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/integrate.htm), but backup your data first

Comment: If you try Integrate and it does not work then describing precisely what you tried (tools and parameter values) would form a focused question).  Asking for tips is too broad.

Comment: For a similar problem in QGIS, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/319412/simplifying-multiple-lines-to-create-central-axis  Creating a dissolved buffer around railway tracks could be a start to resolve the problem, in ArcGIS as well as QGIS.

Comment: thank you guys, @BERA, @PolyGeo and @babel ! I`ve tried Interate, but the results are mixed. In some places it looks VERY cool, but in others it looks awful.
I used the following settings: 
  buffer - 40 meters
integrate - 80 meters
collapse dual line - 300 meters. Intefrate results https://imgur.com/o3VJsoK and Colapse dual lines results https://imgur.com/BeiKzYs

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.