# How to get centerline of each polygon (rectangles) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector, center

How to get centerline of each polygon (rectangles) as in Figure 1 in QGIS to obtain centerlines as in Figure 2

[image]

Figure 1

[image]

Figure 2

Comment: What are the other questions on the same topic on this site miss that is special to yours?

Comment: Maybe here you get some ideas: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/319412/88814