# Calculate a straight or centerline of a polygon

Tags: qgis, line, measurements

I have drawn some roads as polygon and I wish to know if it is possible to calculate how long the roads are.

I imagine that somehow QGIS can figure out the centerline of a polygon and create or calculate the length of the centerline.

I know It is possible to use measure tool but it is pretty inconvenient if you have many polygon roads drawn.

[image]

Comment: Maybe this can give a few ideas: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/319412/88814

Comment: Possible duplicates: 1. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318721/creating-centerline-of-river-in-qgis 2. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33887/finding-centrelines-from-polygons-in-qgis

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize 'geosymplification' by searching and downloading through plugin installation. In chordal axis of geosymplification, compute the centerline though it and use field calculator to get the length of the centerline by entering '$length'.