# Merging highways with two strokes into single path using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, line, merge, road

In QGIS some of my vector layers (shapefiles) for roads have two paths. For highways, I assume this is for divided lanes, but I only want a single path to make it easier to style in Illustrator.

How can I combine the paths into a single one?

Comment: Similar: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/319412/88814

Comment: Could you add a screenshot showing what you have and what you need as a result?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply by installing a plugin named `Topology checker`. You should define a rule to delete parallel lines with a tolerance of `n` meters. Then delete or merge all the closely-paralleled lines. A thorough guide could be found [here](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_topology_checker.html). Good luck.